TikZ Node with not exceeding right page border
I have a beamer presentation where I want to have on top of each frame the title and subtitle of the given frame.
In my beamerouter file, I created the main template for the frames with the following code:
\mode<presentation>
\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{_2023}[1][]
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth, ht=0.4cm]{frametitle}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{MyTitlesMain}  = [anchor=west, font=\headingfont\fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont]
    \tikzstyle{MyTitles}      = [anchor=west, font=\headingfont\fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont\bfseries, inner sep=1pt]
  
    \node[MyTitlesMain] (Title) at ({$(current page.north)!0.025!(current page.south)$} -| {$(current page.west)!0.05!(current page.east)$}) {\insertframetitle};
    \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
    {
    }
    \else%
    {
      \node[MyTitles, text=green] (TitleSep) at (Title.east)    {|};
      \node[MyTitles]             (SubTitle) at (TitleSep.east) {\insertframesubtitle};
    }%
    \fi
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{beamercolorbox}
\mode<all>

Here is the main TeX file:
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, 14pt, notes]{beamer}
\usepackage{beamertheme_2023}
\setbeamersize
{
  text margin left=0.2cm,
  text margin right=0.2cm
}

\setlength\leftmargini{5.0mm}
\setlength\leftmarginii{7.0mm}
\setlength\leftmarginiii{9.0mm}
\setlength\leftmarginiv{11.0mm}
\setbeameroption{hide notes}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, circuits.ee.IEC.relay, datavisualization.formats.functions, decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.markings, fadings, fit, graphs, intersections, math, patterns, positioning, shapes, shadows, through, tikzmark}

\newcommand{\DocumentTitle}{Title of the document}
\newcommand{\DocumentSubtitle}{Subtitle of the document}
\newcommand{\DocumentVersion}{-}
\newcommand{\CopyrightYears}{2024}
\newcommand{\BeamerLastFrame}{0}
\title{\DocumentTitle}
\subtitle{\DocumentSubtitle}
\author{Me}
\institute{Oupsy}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \titlepage
  \end{frame}

  \section{Adding file to the file system}
    \begin{frame}
      \frametitle{This is my slide title. Not so long}
      \framesubtitle{This is my slide subtitle, which goes out since it is quite long}
      test 1
    \end{frame}
\end{document}

The problem is when both title and subtitle are quite long.
In that case, it happens that the subtitle simply does not fit within the page width.
So I wanted to limit the width of the last node (for the subtitle) to ensure it doesn't go outside the right page border.
Does any one have any hint?
Here's a little preview of what I would like to have:

Thanks,

Please provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), which we can compile! It will help us to help you!

Please note that \tikzstyle is deprecated. Have a look at the tikz user guide for \tikzset

@Zarko, I've added normally everything.

@Krzysztof What should happen if the subtitle is too long? Split it over multiple lines?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, thanks for the advice, I will check it later when I will have some time.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, Yes, that is what I would like to.

\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabto}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,sep=0.2cm]{frametitle}
    \fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont \insertframetitle\bfseries\ \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
    \else
      \textcolor{green}{|}
      \tabto{\CurrentLineWidth}
      \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\paperwidth-0.4cm-\TabPrevPos}{\insertframesubtitle}
    \fi
\end{beamercolorbox}
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
\framesubtitle{title}
content...
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title title title title}
\framesubtitle{title title title title title title title title title title title title title title}
content...
\end{frame}
\end{document}



Yes but this is not quite the result I want. I would like to have the subtitle wrap to the right of the title. I will try to put an example in a few minutes...

@Krzysztof See my updated answer

Thanks for your answer @samcarte_is_at_topanswer.xyz.
Nevertheless, I found this post Distance computation (answer from Alain Matthes), which inspired me, and thanks to this, I do not need to change the whole code or load additional packages.
So with that in mind, here is my new template code:
  \else%
  {
    \node[MyTitles, text=green] (TitleSep) at (Title.east)    {|};

    \coordinate (SubTitleXBeg) at (TitleSep.east);
    \coordinate (SubsitleXEnd) at (TitleSep.east -| current page.east);
    \path (SubTitleXBeg) let   \p1 = ($ (SubTitleXBeg) - (SubsitleXEnd) $),  \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)} in -- (SubsitleXEnd)
      node[MyTitles, pos=0.00]  { \begin{varwidth}{\n1}
                                    \insertframesubtitle
                                  \end{varwidth}
                                };
  }%


Thank you for answering your own question. However, the answer would be even more useful if you would extend the code to a compilable example. Then users with similar questions could simply copy and paste to see if this answer is useful to them. Copying code from the question and then replacing parts of the code, on the other hand, creates additional potential mistakes for some users.

@cabohah, I agree, but you can see that I just change the code within the else condition of the whole code written in my question.
